# How do I launch PowerShell 3.0?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've installed the Windows Management Framework 3.0 CTP, which includes PowerShell 3.0.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27548

But now I can't figure out how to launch a PowerShell 3.0 shell. I don't see a new PowerShell installation folder with a powershell.exe to execute.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have installed the CTP, when you run Powershell, it does run the v3.0.

You can do `$PSVersionTable` to verify.

If you want to run the v2.0 engine, you can do `powershell -version 2.0`

Note that Powershell, as was the case with v2.0, still installs onto the v1.0 folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just checked $PSVersionTable but it is showing 2.0. Maybe I need to reboot - will try a reboot later and then circle back to this thread to confirm.

Comment: Yep - seemed like I need a reboot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a new folder.  Just launch Powershell, like normal after the install and you should be running V3.  Run get-host and it should tell you your version number is 3.0.